# How to get object from NSNotification object (Core Data)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I can access the notification received from `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` when I add/edit/delete Core Data values.

I am getting the following data from `userInfo`:

```
Optional([deleted: {(
    <Product: 0x7f8d1a634370> (entity: Product; id: 0xd0000000002c0000 <x-coredata://A9A941BF-C4BA-4E1F-972D-F188032C93E0/Product/p11> ; data: {
    amount = 54;
    date = "2016-01-10 17:16:53 +0000";
    name = test65;
})
)}, managedObjectContext: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7f8d1a705040>])
```

But I can't managed to retrieve the Product object that changed, so I can access his attributes (amount, date, name).

I can see there is a [`NSObject: AnyObject]` dictionary, but still I can't get the object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation says:

> The notification `object` is the managed object context. The `userInfo`
>   dictionary contains the following keys: `NSInsertedObjectsKey`,
>   `NSUpdatedObjectsKey`, and `NSDeletedObjectsKey`.

The value of each key – if available – is a `Set` of `NSManagedObject` objects.

```
if deletedObjects = userInfo[NSDeletedObjectsKey] as? Set<Product> {
  for product in deletedObjects {
    print(product.amount)
  }
}
```

Comment: the deletedObjects returns nil. Not sure why.

Comment: It could also be a `Set`

Comment: Yeah, its a set, but I am still confuse, for example, how to retrieve from this set, lets say the "amount" attribute, it doesn;t seem Set has a subscript operator.

Comment: They are `Product` objects, just call the property `product.amount`

Comment: Yeah, but first  I need the Product object from Set, and I don't see any subscript operator to access the first object for example, and then access amount attribute.

Comment: Just enumerate the `Set` as usual, I updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You have to cast type AnyObject to Product

```
guard let products = notification.userInfo?[NSDeletedObjectsKey] as? [Product] else {
    return
}
// you can use your products here
```

Comment: It always goes on to else clause. So it doesn't retrieve the product from my test.

Comment: notification.userInfo?[NSDeletedObjectsKey] is a Set, not Array